# Изменить работу класса mailer в Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть задача добавить событие (отправку смс) при приоритете задачи немедленный.

Дошел до /redmine/app/models/mailer.rb

вижу такое

```
:subject => "[#{issue.project.name} - #{issue.tracker.name} ##{issue.id}] (#{issue.status.name}) #{issue.subject}"
```

т.е. у isssue должен быть метод issue.priority? и если он immediate, то запусти сторонний скрипт с параметрами

сам в руби не силен

пробую

```
if issue.priority? == "Нормальный"
   system("php /var/www/redmine/app/models/run.php")
end
```

получаю

NoMethodError (undefined method `priority?' for #):

версия 2.5.2.stable

Answer (score 0):

```
# Builds a mail for notifying to_users and cc_users about a new issue
def issue_add(issue, to_users, cc_users)
  redmine_headers 'Project' => issue.project.identifier,
                  'Issue-Id' => issue.id,
                  'Issue-Author' => issue.author.login
  redmine_headers 'Issue-Assignee' => issue.assigned_to.login if issue.assigned_to
  message_id issue
  references issue
  @author = issue.author
  @issue = issue
  @users = to_users + cc_users
  @issue_url = url_for(:controller => 'issues', :action => 'show', :id => issue)
  mail :to => to_users.map(&:mail),
    :cc => cc_users.map(&:mail),
    :subject => "[#{issue.project.name} - #{issue.tracker.name} ##{issue.id}] (#{issue.status.name}) #{issue.subject}"

  if issue.priority.name == "Нормальный"
      system("php /var/www/redmine/app/models/run.php #{issue.id}")   
  end   

end
```

Нормальный - это name из таблицы enumerations